# Salesforce in Teiid

Tags: salesforce, teiid

`subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"> <resource-adapters> <resource-adapter> <connection-definitions> <connection-definition class-name="org.teiid.resource.adapter.file.FileManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/fileDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="teiid-file-ds"> <config-property name="ParentDirectory">/home/rareddy/testing/<config-property> <config-property name="AllowParentPaths">true<config-property> <connection-definition> <connection-definitions> <resource-adapter> <resource-adapters> <subsystem`

What are the values I have to add on

connection-definition class-name
config-property name
ParentDirectory

I took translator as salesforce and took object by connecting with salesforce account.

Comment: See https://teiid.gitbooks.io/documents/content/admin/Salesforce_Data_Sources.html

https://github.com/teiid/teiid/blob/master/connectors/salesforce/feature-pack-salesforce/src/main/resources/content/docs/teiid/datasources/salesforce/salesforce.xml

Comment: What is the driver I need to use for salesforce.I have H2 ,Teiid and Teiid local. @ramesh Reddy

Comment: No driver needed, it uses a Rest based connection. Above resource adapter is enough for connection. If you are working with Teiid embedded then connection semantics are different